# How can I include dot files in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

I would like to configure Nautilus to include files like .bashrc etc by default. They have been intentionally omitted, however, I find myself needed to work with them often enough that it would be convenient to have them view-able all the time.

Also is there a way to at least tell Nautilus to include dot files?

Thanks!

Comment: When you say "dot files", do you mean hidden files?

Comment: They are hidden by default. Any file starting with a ".", like .bashrc

Comment: And do you want hidden folders (starting with a dot) to also be shown by default?

Comment: That would be excellent.